# Multiseat in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, udev, multiseat

I have a Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop machine with one Intel Integrated graphic card and one PCI graphic card.I want to implement Multiseat (2 seats) configuration with own set of keyboards, mice, and monitors providing a traditional desktop experience to each user.
Please tell me what config files i have to edit. and please guide me about every single step to implement this. I am new to linux.
Thanks you very much in advance

output of `lspci | grep VGA` is

```
sardar@sardar-HP-Compaq-6200-Pro-MT-PC:~$ lspci |grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rage XL PCI (rev 27)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of: `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: Thanks Wild Man...  I edited my question with lspci | grep VGA reports..  please help

Answer (score 0):

You can find most of the details [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg_multiseat)

There are two files you need to look at. The /etc/X11/xorg.conf and the appropriate file depending on your [desktop manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg_multiseat#Setting_up_the_loginmanager) (Gnome, KDE, etc.)

If you are trying to multiseat from one graphics card, it will be a different process and as far as I know, possible with extra software, but more difficult. It looks like you are using two different video cards so you should be safe.

Configuring the DE (Desktop environment) files are fairly easy and you can find the instructions on the link above. For the xorg, you will need to do most of the details yourself. Read over [this page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html). The idea is to link your Screens, Inputs, Monitors, Device, etc. to the appropriate ServerLayout set in your DE config file.

Have fun and good luck!

Comment: Thanks your Dear ... I will try to configure multiseat as the link provided by you says..  I have one PCI graphic card (ATI) and one Intel onboard graphic (Intel).. and in ubuntu 13.10, I can't find Xorg.conf, there is no such file.. and I have lightdm as display manager ..  thanks again

Comment: I believe most systems are switching to a config where the xorg.conf is no longer required. This doesn't mean you cannot use it. In recovery mode you can log into root and then use  `X -configure`, then cp the the generated file with `cp xorg.conf.new /etx/X11`. I think the way to do this without recovery mode is `sudo X :1 -configure`.